# To what extent does the AC series answer its own questions?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

I have just finished playing Assassins Creed (1) and before deciding whether I wish to play all titles in the serie I would like to know whether the series only asks more and more questions, without answering them adequately or whether it solves as much mysteries as it introduces. I have a vague recollection that a friend once said that the former was the case, however since then it has been a couple of years, so I am harbouring some hope that this has changed.

For those who require specific definitions in the context of this question  I will define adequately if at least 2/3 of the major questions from the previous games are answered. Major questions would for example things like (though those are just the ones I am most curious about right now):

- Who made the signs at the end of AC (1) and what do they mean?
- What are the Pieces of Eden and who made them and why do they show a map of each other?

Comment: How would you define adequately?

Comment: Which questions did you actually have in mind?

Comment: @Frank: Updated the question

Comment: @user85756: Updated the question

Answer (score 5):

Both of your questions are answered in later games (somewhere in the Ezio trilogy).
However, each game definitely introduces more mysteries. I would say they solve/answer as many mysteries as they introduce.
In 2 and onward, there's additional side non-Assassin-y things to do that provide more backstory and raise questions about the history of that universe.
If you enjoyed accessing the computers and reading their e-mails, I think you would enjoy these side bits of the later games.

Answer (score 2):

I think the series so far is one of the most intriguing series of games I have ever played.

It adds more questions but never leaving you hanging with no answers for some.

They give you excellent things to think about and they support all the lore with the comic books as well and the AC Initiates Website.

I recommend you start playing the rest of the series. You will get satisfying answers and also mysteries to keep you interested.

More specifically for your case, the questions that you have from AC 1 will all be answered in the Ezio Trilogy. And if you want more information you can try the AC: Bloodlines game on the PSP to have more insight of Altair's path after AC 1. Or try the book Secret Crusade from Oliver Bowden.

Hope I helped!

Comment: @DavidMulder please review my answer to see if you might want to accept it for others to find it if they have questions similar to yours.